# Check if a variable is a string of numbers like "1234"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a small interactive text game in python.
i need to check if a string, from the user, is `1234` (a number in a string that would work with `int()` ) or `foo` (just a string, python would traceback if I called `int()` on it)

```
while(True):
    IN = input("[Number] >> ")
    if(isNumber(IN)):
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a number.")
        continue
IN = int(IN) #guaranteed to work at this point
someFunction(IN)
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything or are you just looking for people to do it for you?

Comment: This is really not good example code. For one thing, it's not legal code (missing a colon after the `def`, missing an indent after the `def`). And it's confusing to use `/if` for `else`, even in a comment. And `standardin` is not a builtin function, so how do we know what it runs (Is it a `str` or a `bytes`? Does it include a trailing newline? And so on.) And most of the code seems irrelevant to the problem. Also, the bizarre mix of capitalization styles, unnecessary parentheses, etc. don't help. Please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know if something is "a number in a string, one that would work with int()", you do that by just calling [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
try:
    i = int(myvar)
    # It's an int, and we have the value if you want it
except ValueError:
    # It's not an int
```

This is a general case of the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) principle: It's Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission. Instead of trying to guess whether something would fail, it's usually easier to just try it and see if it fails.

That's especially try in cases where trying to guess is more complicated than it looks. For example, people always suggest using the [`isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method here, but that fails in a number of cases. For example:

- `isdigit` is false for negative numbers, because the `'-'` character is not a digit.
- `isdigit` is false for numbers with trailing whitespace (e.g., because you're not `rstrip`ping newlines from your input).
- `isdigit` is true for hundreds of non-western digits and special-form digits that can't be used with `int`.
- `int` has changed its rules at least twice between Python 2.0 and 3.4, and could always change again.

You probably *could* come up with a complicated rule that was exactly the same as "would work with int()" as interpreted in some specific Python version, but why, when `int` is  obviously guaranteed to always do the same thing as `int`?

Comment: Excellent explanation and +1 for mentioning EAFP.

Comment: thanks @abarnert also inadvertently explained 'try' for me :D